# Retrieve Google Traffic Status

Tags: google-maps, traffic

I been looking around with no luck. I am trying to retrieve the Google Data Traffic for a given route.

Is anyway to retrieve that info using the Google Maps API? I need to get the status of the route each 10 minutes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ovi has a map api.  You may want to try looking at it: http://api.maps.ovi.com/